# Send push notification via browser in Android/iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, browser, push-notification

I have been searching for the best, easy solution to send notification via browser. What is the best solution to send push notification to android/ios device within a browser? I found pubnub, but that is not working with mobile devices.

Comment: Easiest way by far is to implement Parse.com. Works on all platforms and you can send notifications to 1mil devices for free.

Comment: what do you mean **pubnub is not working for mobile devices** ????  it's the world's main delivery service for presence for mobile devices!!!

Comment: yes, Parse works fine.  but normally whenever you start doing this in Parse, you say "well it's so much easier with PubNub I'll just do that".  some like Firebase as well

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do it.

First have a look at the first step implementation - [Push Notifications on the open web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en) by Google Developers itself.

I have tried/used these two and feel they are good enough-

[Chrome Push](https://storage-cdn.realtime.co/chrome-push/index.html) - Code example on [Github](https://github.com/realtime-framework/ChromePushNotifications)

[Gooroost](https://goroost.com/try-web-push)

Hope it helps.

Comment: As long as its chrome, it will work on all platforms. Android, ios, PC(Win, Linux, MAC OSX), etc., Chrome Push works across platforms for sure.

Comment: Adding to that, Gooroost also has cross platform support is what I see. Have a look at both the options and choose what suits you the best :) Happy coding!